# How can I improve my algorithm for detecting array elements that correspond to the same fraction?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, duplicates

This is the algorithm im using to compare two fractions. `uper` is an array of all the numerators and `under` is an array of all denominators, so one of the fractions is `uper[i]/under[j]`. I want to print all the positions that have the same fraction. They're already the standard form

Can you think of a better approach?

```
 for(i = 0; i < (length-1); i++)
    for(j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
        if(uper[i] == uper[j]
          if (under[i] == under[j])
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
```

Comment: same fraction, they're already the standard form

Answer (score 1):

Same fractions can be treated as different according to your algo.
To compare if two fractions like `a/b` and `c/d` are equal, check `if(a*d==b*c)`

So your code must look like

```
for(i = 0; i < (length-1); i++)
for(j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
    if(uper[i]*under[j] == uper[j]*under[i])
        printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
```

Comment: i've tried it and the execution time increased, the fractions are already in the standard form, thus i can compare the uper and under

Answer (score 0):

Same fraction or same equivalent fraction? 3/4 is equivalent to 6/8. Do you want to compare also this kind of thing?

If so, you can use:

```
if(upper[i]*under[j] == upper[j]*under[i]) {
    printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
}
```

If not, I think your solution is the best way.